# How to use this "twister-lib-js" library in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, cryptojs

https://github.com/Adeon18/Twister
I want to achieve same in React Native, can you guys help me.
Twister community is small and I want to be able to do this.
I tried various methods found on internet, but they didn’t work.

Comment: "twister-lib-js" Any one implemented this library in react native? Please help

Comment: Thanks for your question. However, SO is not a "code ordering" service where you can order entire libraries written by SO users. When you have a problem, feel free to share, what exactly troubles you and what you've already tried to solve this very problem.